# jBPM 6.2.0 send recurring Task reminder after 1 day time interval if the task is not complete

Tags: events, timer, signals, task, jbpm

I am new to jBPM. I am working on jBPM version 6.2.0. I want to perform following tasks.

1. Send reminder email to user / group. 
   Remind the user again after 1 business day if the task is not yet complete. Continue to send reminder everyday untill the task is done.
2. Also what happens if jboss / tomcat server restarts after sending one reminder email. Will the later emails still schedule ?

I am able to add Deadlines (Escalation- Notification) But it runs once and sends only 1 email. I need to keep reminding the user on a daily basis (or hourly) to complete the task.
I tried looking in jBPM 6 user guide but it does not have clarity about Boundary timer events and intermediate catch time events. And when i use any of them then it runs once.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of something that I did recently for sending periodic emails.

[image: Example Timer Loop]

This should loop until a user finally completes the task. You might have trouble with the one business day rule since I do not know if the ISO 8601 spec is flexible enough to know about weekends/holidays/business days. You could add that logic into your service task for sending the email.

Be aware that this loop will continue forever until the task is complete. You might want to consider adding some additional timeout. You could add a loop count so after X amount of times the process will be cancelled. Some of my processes have a rule that if the process is not complete in Y days, the process should be cancelled. I accomplished that by have a process variable CancelDate and set a Timer Event definition to Date/Time and the value #{CancelDate}.